# Splitting YCrCb image to its intensity channels

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I want to split **YCrCb** to Y, Cr, and Cb channels.

Code works well but when I show the channels with `imshow("Y", y)` for each Y, Cr, Cb, all channels look grey.

Only Y channel must be grey the others are supposed to be colorful. Am I right? Or what is the problem with code?

```
    Mat RGBImage;
    RGBImage = imread("xx.jpg");    
    cvtColor(RGBImage, YCrCb, CV_RGB2YCrCb);

    vector<Mat> ycc_planes;
    split(YCrCb, ycc_planes);

    Mat y = ycc_planes[0];
    Mat Cr = ycc_planes[1];
    Mat Cb = ycc_planes[2];
```

My final goal is to apply mean filter to image's Y component and then to change it back to RGB with merging other components (Cr and Cb) . Finally I am going to get a blurry version of original RGB image. However my mean filter returns always grey blurry image. I though it may be so because of my Cr, Cb components are grey.

Comment: You're splitting a 3-channel image into 3 1-channel images. 1-channel images are grayscale, and will be displayed as gray-sh. The fact that their pixel values is actually a color information is irrelevant, they are still grayscale images. So, your code is OK, just your interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: What should I add to my code in order to make them colorful? @Miki

Comment: `cvtColor(RGBImage, YCrCb, CV_BGR2YCrCb);` maybe better

Comment: Oh, maybe I get it... you mean something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Barns_grand_tetons_YCbCr_separation.jpg)? This is just a colormap, a visual effect.

Comment: Yes, and actually I apply mean filter to image's Y component and I need to change it back to RGB with merging other components (Cr and Cb) . Finally I am going to get a blurry version of original RGB image. However my mean filter returns always grey blurry image. I though it may so because of my Cr, Cb components are grey. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: Maybe you want [this](http://bit.ly/112eh4q), right? Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL6tlz3Oc-zFi9cMVoT9Q2RsM_xvQmCrJM&v=hEFXUytWTEQ) at 3:41

Comment: Thank you @Berriel nice video! =)

Comment: OpenCV images are stored as BGR

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you split a 3 channel image into 3 single channel image, each image is grayscale. The fact that they represent color information is irrelevant.

Original image:

[image]

YCrCb channels:

[image]

You can, however, apply a color effect:

[image]

---

You can blur the Y channel, and then merge the 3 single channels, and convert back to BGR:

[image]

Here the full code for reference:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat3b bgr = imread("path_to_image");

    Mat3b ycrcb;
    cvtColor(bgr, ycrcb, COLOR_BGR2YCrCb);

    vector<Mat1b> planes;
    split(ycrcb, planes);

    // Collage planes
    Mat1b collagePlanes(bgr.rows, bgr.cols*3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        planes[i].copyTo(collagePlanes(Rect(i*bgr.cols, 0, bgr.cols, bgr.rows)));
    }

    Mat1b gray(bgr.rows, bgr.cols, uchar(128));

    // Y
    vector<Mat1b> vy(3);
    vy[0] = planes[0];
    vy[1] = gray.clone();
    vy[2] = gray.clone();
    Mat3b my;
    merge(vy, my);

    // Cr
    vector<Mat1b> vcr(3);
    vcr[0] = gray.clone();
    vcr[1] = planes[1];
    vcr[2] = gray.clone();
    Mat3b mcr;
    merge(vcr, mcr);

    // Cb
    vector<Mat1b> vcb(3);
    vcb[0] = gray.clone();
    vcb[1] = gray.clone();
    vcb[2] = planes[2];
    Mat3b mcb;
    merge(vcb, mcb);



    // Collage planes
    Mat3b collageColor(bgr.rows, bgr.cols * 3);
    my.copyTo(collageColor(Rect(0, 0, bgr.cols, bgr.rows)));
    mcr.copyTo(collageColor(Rect(bgr.cols, 0, bgr.cols, bgr.rows)));
    mcb.copyTo(collageColor(Rect(2 * bgr.cols, 0, bgr.cols, bgr.rows)));

    cvtColor(collageColor, collageColor, COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);


    ////////////////////////////

    // Blur Y
    boxFilter(planes[0], planes[0], CV_8U, Size(7,7));

    Mat3b blurred;
    merge(planes, blurred);
    cvtColor(blurred, blurred, COLOR_YCrCb2BGR);


    imshow("Original", bgr);
    imshow("YCrCb planes", collagePlanes);
    imshow("YCrCb planes colored", collageColor);
    imshow("Blurred", blurred);
    waitKey();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wow!! Thank you so much for the answer I've learned a lot asking this question!  =)) @Miki

Answer (score 3):

As @[Miki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5008845) said in the comments, splitting a 3-channel image will give you 3 1-channel images, and 1-channel images are grayscale! Also, @[sturkmen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5294258/sturkmen) pointed out an important thing: OpenCV images are stored as BGR, so you need to use `CV_BGR2YCrCb` instead of `CV_RGB2YCrCb` in the `cvtColor`.

However, I see a lot of materials showing them (the individual channels) in a colorful manner, like [this](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs143/lectures/03.pdf) from Professor Hays.

If you want to see them that way, you need to set a fixed value to the other channels and merge them back. This way you can achieve the first row of the image below. The second row are the individual channels. For more info you can read this [post](http://bit.ly/112eh4q) or watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL6tlz3Oc-zFi9cMVoT9Q2RsM_xvQmCrJM&v=hEFXUytWTEQ).

[image: YCrCb sample]

Comment: Nice blog btw, now I know what to link when SO users have problems installing OpenCV :D